# how to create multiple filters from one dimension tableau (10)?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a two dimensions with the following data set

**Original Dimension**

[image]

I would like to create two filters that can be used to filter my dashboard. These two filter would be called - "Product_Type" and "Product" and should have the following drop downs:

**Filter Breakdown**

[image]

To summarize, I am looking for a way to take my original dimension and create the filter breakdowns so that in my dashboard I can have two filter (Product_type and Product). When i click on the Product_type filter, i should be able to see "overall", "fruits", "vegetable" and "leafy. Based on my selection , the Product filter should automatically show only the relevant values - i.e. if i picked "leafy" it should only show "spinach" and "kale". Finally if i select "kale" my entire dashboard should change accordingly.

Looking for a way to do this without drastically affecting the performance.

update: i was able to achieve this by creating multiple parameters and then using the pop window technique (https://vimeo.com/107352893) - but this has affected my workbook performance very badly. Need another solution!!

Comment: @Alex Blakemore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish your desired functionality by creating a calculated field for product type and a CASE statement to classify the products based on the product type you specified your image.

Further, filters can be configured to display available values based on the other filters in place.  I would recommend having your Product Type filter a the "context" or "data-source" level, and your product filter at the lowest level, so that the selectable options for the product filter can be displayed using the "only relevant Values" option and limits the products that can be chosen.

Please see the following link for some more information on filtering hierarchies

- [Performance Related](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#filtering_context.html%3FTocPath%3DBuilding%2520Data%2520Views%7CFiltering%7CContext%2520Filters%7C_____0)
- [General Filtering](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering.html)
- [Blog Post](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-10054)

"Only relevant values - Specifies which values to show in the filter. When you select this option other filters are considered and only values that pass these filters are shown. For example, a filter on State will only show the Eastern states when a filter on Region is set. You can use the toggle at the top of the filter card to switch between this option and the All Values in Database option.

All values in database - Specifies which values to show in the filter. When you select this option all values in the database are shown regardless of the other filters on the view.

All values in context (Tableau Desktop only) - When one of the filters in the view is a context filter, select this option on a different filter to only display values that pass through the context filter. For more information, see Improve View Performance with Context Filters."

Comment: This works. I'd only add that you can use Tableau's group feature to more easily create your product type field. But the effect is the same as a case statement